# How to avoid feeling alone when working from home?

Tags: socializing, work-from-home

So, I've been working on this company as a software developer for almost 2 years now and lately, we've been changed to a home office regime, which was great at first but now I'm starting to miss chatting with my coworkers, getting my head away from coding for a while and stuff like that. As a result, I'm feeling kinda lonely. Is there anything I can do to feel less lonely when working from home?

Comment: Does the entire team works from home all the time? Otherwise. you can have a common day / date fixed, where you all can go to office to have some F2F time, and work from home the rest of the time.

Comment: or, do you have a [coworking space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coworking) near you?

Comment: Was this your decision to work from home? What move you to make that decision? The conditions are still the same? Can you move back?

Comment: How about using a video chat room and keeping it open for remote workers to join in. Or ask your workplace if they can add a tablet with a video chat room to the coffee machine, so that remote workers can join in and have a coffee chat.

Comment: To the mods:Why was this closed ?  I think co-working space is a very useful relevant answer here that didn't exist when the  question was asked originally. Answers can evolve over time even if the questions are the same

Comment: @Hilmar - you could reply to the original question with a new answer if you think it is suitable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The company I work for has some remote parts and I heard about a few things in a presentation by a full remote software engineer.
Here are some things you can do:

- Maintain contact with your friends, maybe meet them some time for lunch. Hobbies are a nice way to expand your circle of friends.
- Work outside more often, in cafes for example. If you're a regular in some cafes, the baristas may also get to know you and chat with you.
- Work in co-working spaces.
- Establish a video chatting room for your co-workers and yourself, where anyone can drop in to have a chat.
- Establish 1on1s to keep up with co-workers. There are slack bots for that. They match you with a colleague each week. Have a 10-30 min remote coffee chat.
- If there are still people at the companies site you could ask for a tablet with a video chat room at the coffee machine, so that the remote workers could join in.